# Import doesn't work in command line

Tags: java, class, import, io, ioexception

I have a slow netbook so i installed lubuntu then geany on it to make it a little useful. C++ seems to work flawless however with java i couldn't get it to work. Searching online didn't return anything.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

class asdf{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("Nothing");
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
root@*****:/home/***/Documents# javac asdf.java
asdf.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
throws java.io.IOException {
    symbol:   class io
    location: class java
    ./java.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    throws java.io.IOException {
        symbol:   class io
        location: class java
    2 errors
```

Now, i know you guys don't like clueless newcomers but i got this error while i was trying to learn java from a book, namely "Java : A Beginner's Guide".

I have almost no idea since i'm a beginner still i have a feeling this has something to do with path and building. Since IDEs always handled that for me i never bothered with such stuff. Or i may have damaged my packages somehow considering "import java.io.*;" returns no error.

```
javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131
```

The way i installed oracle java is [here](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/).

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you reinstall JDK. I tried same thing on my Ubuntu 16 and everything works as expected.

Comment: I tried that now and it seems i have some serious stuff going on. Uninstall returned an error code. I'm running low on battery i'll try further when i get home. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: anonim what OS do you have? Ubuntu 16?

Comment: Lubuntu 17.04 zesty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so silly, the folder i tried to compile the command "import java.io.*", included a file named java.java so the compiler tried to import it from this file. Thanks to all those who tried to help. I uninstalled android studio and oracle java for no reason (facepalm here).

Answer (score -1):

Try to install openjdk on your lubuntu.
First delete Oracle jdk.
Type `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk` in your terminal.

And another thing. Name of a class should start from capital letter.

Comment: It's not the solution, having Oracle JDK is perfectly OK

Comment: Hmm, i heard openjdk is worse than oracle java? Also i hate capital letters it slows down typing, as long as my file name is in sync i should be ok right?

Comment: @anonim it's an almost universal convention among Java programmers to start class names with a capital letter. If you don't, you might confuse readers of your code. Also, all the Java API classes start with a capital letter, so you might as well be consistent.

Comment: @Gondy it's easier to just type the command in terminal to install JDK than downloading zip, unzip and finally defining JAVA_HOME and other variables. I didn't mean that Oracle JDK is not as good as openjdk

Comment: Umm, JAVA_HOME ? I don't recall defining that. Maybe that was the problem?